# Create a comment | Google-SpreadSheet | nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to put a comment using NODEJS and the "Google Spread-Sheet" module, I have managed to write in cells, read, delete, but I can not put a comment in a cell, and the tutorials I see only teach discontinued forms, someone could help me? thank you very much.

```
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet');
const creds = require('./googleSheetCredentials.json');

async function accessSpreadSheet() {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('XXXXXXXXXXXX');
    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds);
    await doc.loadInfo();
    const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];

    await sheet.addRow({
        Login: 'hello world', // column A
        Date: '2020-01-01' // column B
    });

    const row = await sheet.getRows();
    console.log(row);

    //await sheet.addComment('2', 'Login', 'Hello world'); Doesn't work 
}

accessSpreadSheet();
```

Comment: Welcome to stack.  Can you edit your question and add a link to the method in the API documentation where it shows you can add comments to cells.

Comment: You can't attach a comment to a cell. Comments are linked to the drive (notes are attached to cells)

Comment: @MikeSteelson Okay, it's my bad, you know where is the official documentation? or how can put a note into a cell?, thanks :=)

Comment: You can refer to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotenote with gas. But I don't know how to integrate with node.js

Comment: In your script, if you want to insert a note to a cell, what do you want to do at `await sheet.addComment('2', 'Login', 'Hello world');`? Do you want to put a note of `Hello world` to the column "A" of the added row? First, I thought that I would like to correctly understand your goal. I apologize for this.

Comment: By guessing your goal, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to insert a note to a cell.

  - From your showing script and `await sheet.addComment('2', 'Login', 'Hello world');`, I guessed that you wanted to insert a note to the column "A" of the added row.
- You want to achieve this using [node-google-spreadsheet](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet).

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet');
const creds = require('./googleSheetCredentials.json');

async function accessSpreadSheet() {
  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('XXXXXXXXXXXX');
  await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds);
  await doc.loadInfo();
  const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];

  // I modified below script.
  const res = await sheet.addRow({
    Login: "hello world", // column A
    Date: "2020-01-01", // column B
  });
  await sheet.loadCells();
  sheet.getCellByA1("A" + res.rowIndex).note = "sample note";
  await sheet.saveUpdatedCells();
}

accessSpreadSheet();
```

- When you run this script, a note of `sample note` is inserted into the column "A" of the added row.

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that you have already been able to get and put values to Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API with `google-spreadsheet` and your script of `await sheet.addRow` works. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [node-google-spreadsheet](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: that's work for me, thank you

Comment: @abello-r Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.